# Match hotmail returned email_hashes with the emails in my database

Tags: php, email, encryption, hotmail

I was able to import user's contacts:

```
        $url = 'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?access_token='.$accesstoken.'';
        $xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
        $xml = json_decode($xmlresponse, true);
        foreach($xml['data'] as $emails)
        {
                echo '<br><br>';
                echo $emails['name'].' '.$emails['email_hashes'][0];

        }
```

The thing is that I want to find the connections the user might have in my network. A hotmail doesn't provide the plain text email (and that it looks one way encryption)..

How can I encrypt my emails the same way to compare them? is there any other work around this?

Comment: instead of encrypt your emails,try to decrypt the emails which you get from hotmail

Comment: That's not possible, as the emails are encrypted with a reversible encryption. Instead, they're a sha256 hash calculated from the appid and email address together.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14243561/533941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my solution was to extenD the scope: Then more fields where recived in the result

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={APPID}&`scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic%20wl.emails%20wl.contacts_emails&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://{REDIRECT_URI}`
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826530.aspx#generating) for generating the hashes, you can generate the hash by first `trim()`-ing your appid and the email, concatenating them together as UTF-8 and generating the sha256 hash of the concatenated string.

Something like (pseudoish code), assuming both appid and email are valid utf-8:

```
function get_hotmail_hash($email, $appId)
{
    $content = mb_strtolower(trim($email) . trim($appId), "utf-8");
    return hash("sha256", $content);
}
```

Comment: I got this erorr "Call to undefined function : mb_strotolower"

Comment: @BhavikPatel It should be mb_strtolower, I've corrected the example.